# Can't change my tint color when i selected a tab bar button

Tags: ios, swift

i'm new to swift can some one please help me ?

i've tried adding appearance tintcolor in app delegate it's doesn't work i'm running out of ideas

```
let myTabBar = UITabBar()

myTabBar.tintColor = UIColor.green

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
   myTabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.red
}

let one = UITabBarItem()
    one.title = "Home"
    one.tag = 1
    one.image = UIImage(named: "home")

    myTabBar.delegate = self

 func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    switch item.tag {
    case 1:
        let controller = businessStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BusinessListViewController")
        addChildViewController(controller)
        view.addSubview((controller.view)!)
        controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to get tabBar from TabBarController, and then change tint property

Comment: @ReinierMelian i'm creating tabBar in uiviewcontroller how to get TabBarController for tabBar ?

Comment: You are using TabBarController?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get tabBar from `UITabBarController`, and then change tint property, something like this, assuming that your rootViewController is a `UITabBarController`

```
if let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
        self.configureTabBar(tabBarController:tabBarController)
    }

 func configureTabBar(tabBarController: UITabBarController) {
            // Tab bar customization
        tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor =  UIColor.red
    }
```